# Right way to iterate over record<string, string>

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I'm trying -

```
export function logError(paramsToLog?: Record<string, string>): void {
    const logData: LoggerData[] = [];
    if (paramsToLog) {
        for (const key of paramsToLog) {
            logData.push(LoggerData.create(key, paramsToLog[key]));
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

I see `eslint` complaining - `(parameter) paramsToLog: Record<string, string> Type 'Record<string, string>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.`

Could not find any iterator in record arg.